# Juju Backup Failing

Tags: backup, juju

Juju version 1.20.11-utopic-amd64 fails on backup, as per [Juju documentation - Backup and Restore of the Juju State-Server](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/howto-backup-restore.html):

```
$ juju backups create
ERROR unrecognized command: juju backups
$  juju --version
1.20.11-utopic-amd64
```

In fact "juju help commands" does not list `backups` as an option. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the command. The actual command is `juju backup create`. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enter this in the terminal:

```
juju --version backup create
```

and it might work fine this way.